# What sound mitigation techniques has the Venom symbiote attempted?

Tags: marvel, venom-2018, sonys-marvel-universe

Disclaimer: I've been watching clips of the *Venom* movie on YouTube, so I know essentially nothing about the character.

---

It seems that Venom is susceptible to sound and to fire.  I'm particularly curious about the sound part, because mitigation of sound should be pretty simple.

The symbiote can make teeth capable of, in a single bite, cutting a thoracic vertebra in half.  In a couple of scenes the bad-symbiote makes or shoots hard needles that can cut through metal, plastic, and living creatures caught in the way.  They relatively easily (compared to a human) toss around 2 ton cars.

There is vast strength in their abilities.

They can act on a macro-scale like inches to yards and on a micro-scale like fixing broken bones and tissues or a heart.

Why can't they take a cup of rubber particles and sand particles and make a structure with huge impedance mismatches at the wavelengths of interest so that it blocks the sound?

What physically viable acoustic mitigation strategies have they attempted?

Comment: I've edited to include a title more in line with what I think you are asking. If this isn't correct feel free to update it.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - Thank you.  That works.  I also didn't know how to tag it and you seem to have helped there too.